# Resize Plot Area dynamically to see truncated text in Category Axis of a Clustered Bar Chart

Tags: excel, vba, bar-chart, powerpoint, axis-labels

I am copying and pasting `Clustered Bar charts` from a `Workbook` into a `Powerpoint deck` created dynamically. The Bar charts Category Axis may have long text (Axis labels), that sometimes gets truncated. The `Wrap text` option for Category Axis is `greyed out`. So i want to move the `Plot Area of the Chart to the Right dynamically` to make the Category Axis truncated text visible.

[image]

```
Sub ExportClusteredBarChartsToPowerpoint()
    Dim oPPT As Object: Set oPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    With oPPT
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
    End With

    Dim oPres As Object: Set oPres = oPPT.presentations.Add
    Dim oSlide As Object
    Dim iNdx As Integer
    Dim oChart As ChartObject
    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ChartsSheet")

    iNdx = 1
    With oWS
        For Each oChart In oWS.ChartObjects

            oChart.Chart.ChartArea.Copy

            Set oSlide = oPres.slides.Add(iNdx, 12)       'ppLayoutBlank
            oSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial 0, msoFalse           '0=ppPasteDefault
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            With oSlide.Shapes(1)
                .ScaleWidth 1.75, 0, 1 'msoTrue, msoScaleFromMiddle
                .ScaleHeight 1.75, 0, 1 'msoTrue,msoScaleFromMiddle
                oPPT.Windows(1).View.ZoomToFit = False
                oPPT.Windows(1).View.Zoom = 98
            End With
            iNdx = iNdx + 1
        Next oChart
    End With    
End Sub
```

Is this possible or is there an alternative solution using VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will expand the left axis area by 50 points every time you run it:

```
With oSlide.Shapes(1)
  If .HasChart Then
    With .Chart.PlotArea
      .Width = .Width - 50
      .Left = .Left + 50
    End With
  End If
End With
```

Comment: i need a dynamic way based on text length or word length, say, reduce plot area if average category label word length exceeds the max number of words supported in a category axis label before it truncates text. something on these lines.

Comment: Interesting addition to your original post! You'll have to count characters, then come up with an average character width based on your language, calculate the approximate width and number of lines based on character count, then adjust the chart plot area width and position to make them show.  Feel free to post your code as you develop it, I'm here to help.

Comment: Sorry @john Korchok. I was mulling over too many ideas on how to reduce plotarea dynamically to take care of not only the Category XAxis text but also another issue i came across and i.e. the Chart Title text overflowing the PlotArea. So my comment was made in the midst of that confusion. BTW, your name rings a bell....

Comment: Actually, setting the `PlotArea.Position` property to `xlChartElementPositionAutomatic` somehow seems to do the trick. Though i still had to reduce the Category XAxis font from the default `Arial-12` to `Arial-8`. I would rather have prefered not setting the font properties, but use the chart's default settings.

Comment: Chart VBA is actually in a separate module from Word, because Office uses Excel to provide charting capabilities. But the .Chart addition enables you to access this without too much hassle.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the call-out. Yes, I'm the XML guy, though I do VBA as well.

Comment: Consider me an avid fan. :-) I have used your examples since so many years now. had recently visited and dropped a query on one of your posts.

Comment: `Sub doit()
Dim myChart As Object: Set myChart = ActiveChart
With myChart
        With .PlotArea
            .Select
            .Position = xlChartElementPositionAutomatic 'xlChartElementPositionCustom
            .Top = myChart.ChartTitle.Top + myChart.ChartTitle.Height
            .Height = myChart.Parent.Height - .Top
        End With
End With
End Sub`

Comment: Your code got messed up by the comments formatting. Please note in text what you are trying to show, it seems to be something about chart positioning rather than axis titling space.